# Troubleshooting Jquery Show/Hide With Nested Divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, show, show-hide

I've managed to get this working with:

```
<!--
function resettoggle() {
document.getElementById('imagecarousel').style.display = 'none';

}

function displayImages() {
                document.getElementById$('#imagecarousel').style.display="block";

            }

  $('#imagecarousel').fadeIn("slow", function() {
  // Animation complete


    $('#portfolio').click(function () {
  $("#imagecarousel").toggle();


});
});

-->
```

and adding onLoad="resettoggle()" to the body tag

I now only need help with 2 things:

1. I have the div set to fadeIn, but it seems to be flying in at the speed of light.
2. When the page loads, you see a flicker of the slideshow before it disappears. Not sure how to implement the resettoggle function in a way that keeps the hidden div completely out of view?

Answer (score 2):

you can use [`fadeToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/):

> Display or hide the matched elements by animating their opacity.

```
$("#portfolio").click(function () {
   $("#imagecarousel").fadeToggle("slow");
});
```

Comment: I have made some progress, please see revised code above. Thanks